# JQuery simpleWeather Issue

Tags: jquery, weather

I've been messing with this plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/a4hbL/2064/

I'm trying to display text with JQuery every time a condition is met: if it's sunny outside print "It's Sunny", if it's snowing print "It's Snowing" and etc...

I've tried:

```
if(weather.tomorrow.code === 32) {
        $("#weather").html('<h1>It is Sunny!</h1>');
    }
    else if {
         ... // rest of the possible outputs.
```

But nothing worked (see http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#codes for weather codes). 
I keep getting various errors in the console like *weather is undefined* or *cannot read property of code*.

Here's where I've added it: http://jsfiddle.net/LEJbT/2/

Help is kindly appreciated. I've been stuck without a fix for awhile...

Thanks!

Comment: You are using `weather` outside the scope of where it is defined.  You are doing an AJAX call (i.e. asynchronous), so `weather` is only defined upon successful completion of the call, and only within the scope of the `success` handler.  In your code, you are outside of the scope, and most likely the AJAX query has not completed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Y6s/

You have to put your code in the **success-part**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.simpleWeather({
        zipcode: '',
        woeid: '2357536',
        location: '',
        unit: 'f',

        success: function (weather) {
            html = '<h2>' + weather.tomorrow.high + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
            html += '<ul><li>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</li>';
            html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.tomorrow.forecast + '</li>';
            html += '<li>' + weather.tomorrow.highAlt + '&deg;C</li></ul>';

            $("#weather").html(html);
/************************** your code HAS TO BE here ************************/
    if(weather.tomorrow.code > 16) {
        $("#weather").html('<h1>Alert: Freezing Rain!</h1>');
    }
    else {
         $("#weather").html('<h1>Alert: Freezing Rain!</h1>');
    }


        },
        error: function (error) {
            $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
        }
    });

/************************** your code was here ************************/

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was a placement error but I just couldn't figure it out. Spot on!

Answer (score 0):

For 'weather is undefined' error

You can check ajax success or not by check success function

```
success: function(weather) { 
    console.log(weather);
},
```

And
For 'cannot read property of code' error

You can check the value of weather.tomorrow

```
success: function(weather) { 
    console.log(weather.tomorrow);
},
```